# Custom transposing a list messes up original variable in Python

Tags: python-3.x, transpose

I have this function that should transpose the list it gets. This works, but for some reason it alters the original matrix as well: why?

```
Matrix = [["1"], ["1","2"], ["1","2","3","4"], []]

def test():
    global Matrix # same happens when global or not
    tMatrix = Matrix
    print(tMatrix) # 1
    tMatrix = transposer(Matrix)
    print(tMatrix) # 2
    print(Matrix) # 3
```

Output:

```
[['1'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], []]   # 1
[['1', '1', '1'], ['2', '2'], ['3'], ['4']]     # 2
[[], [], [], []]                                # 3
```

I think it should not matter, but here is the transposer function:

```
def transposer(m):
    tm = []
    maxi = 0
    for i in range(0, len(m)):
        maxi = max(maxi, len(m[i]))
    for z in range(0, maxi):
        row = []
        for j in range(0, len(m)): 
            try:
                row.append(m[j].pop(0))
            except:
                pass
        tm.append(row)
    return(tm)
```

How is it possible that the Matrix variable is also affected even though the function is not called on that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

`tMatrix = Matrix`

in reality you are making `tMatrix` a reference to the original `Matrix` object. So, when you assign the output of the `transposer` function back to `tMatrix` you are really changing the original `Matrix` object itself. This is a very common misunderstanding when you're getting used to python, like you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222440/python-variable-reference-assignment), for example (the answer is worth reading too).

Try to read something on the way Python treats assignments and you'll see the difference from other languages:

http://learnpython.pbworks.com/w/page/15956522/Assignment

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/variables.html

**EDIT:**

To solve the problem, you can make a copy of the original object passed to `transpose` through a [copy operation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

```
def transposer(n):
    m = copy.copy(n)
    tm = []
    maxi = 0
    for i in range(0, len(m)):
        maxi = max(maxi, len(m[i]))
        print i, maxi
    for z in range(0, maxi):
        row = []
        for j in range(0, len(m)): 
            try:
                row.append(m[j].pop(0))
            except:
                pass
        tm.append(row)
    return(tm)
```

Just as a sidenote, you're treating your elements as strings. If they were supposed to be numeric you can just enter them without the `" "`. Also, if you don't need to use your own transposing algorithm, you can just use the [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) package, which already does [matrix transposition](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.transpose.html).

Comment: Might you have a solution for what to do instead? I understand that it is a reference like I saw in C++, but there it is an option to refer to the binding.

Comment: The problem is in the transpose function. When you do `m[j].pop(0)` you are deleting elements from the original `Matrix`, which was passed through `m`. I'm editing my answer so it does it right.

Comment: I found this "copy.deepcopy" from the copy module. I had no idea it was actually popping that was having that side-effect! Thanks.