# Why I can't re-assign a variable in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

Today I find an interesting fact, that I can't re-assign variable in a 'for loop', but why?

Here is my code:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for i in my_list:
>>>     if i > 3:
>>>        i = 'my_value'
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: What did you hope that ``i = "foo"`` would accomplish here? Terminate the loop? When the for loop continues it's next iteration (*NB: Iterators*) ``i`` will point to a new reference object of the next element in the iterator ``[1, 2, 3, 4]``.

Answer (score 5):

When you loop over a list with `for i in my_list`, `i` isn't bound to a list cell on each iteration. It's bound to the object the list cell referred to. Assigning a new value to `i` binds `i` to a new object, but there's no link between `i` and the list that would cause the list cell to be affected.

An equivalent way to loop over a list would be

```
for index in range(len(my_list)):
    i = my_list[index]
    whatever_loop_body()
```

Hopefully, it's clearer in this formulation that `i` is not an alias for the list cell. (Don't actually loop over lists like this.)

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, you want to have a result like the following

```
[1, 2, 3, 'my_value', 'my_value']
```

To do this, you need to do this:

```
['my value' if i > 3 else i for i in x]
```

### Update

Why your code doesn't work? Because `i` is not a reference to an object but a primitive value assignment. [Python variable reference assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222440/python-variable-reference-assignment).

### Update 2

If the element of the list is an object rather than a primitive, then it seems that `i` become a reference to that object.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val

my_list = [A(1), A(2),A(3),A(4),A(5)]
for i in my_list:
   if i.value > 3:
       i.value = 'my_value'

print([i.value for i in my_list])
# [1, 2, 3, 'my_value', 'my_value']
```

### Update 3

Please see some of the discussion in the comment below. In python, everything is an object. No primitive.

Ref: [For Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for)

Comment: -1 His question is `why?`, not `how?`

Comment: oh sorry, I misinterpret his question,. I'll rewrite my answer

Comment: `i` *is* a reference, contrary to what you’ve said.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Could you help me to verify if my second update, correct? If not, any suggestion.

Comment: @Yeo In the second case, you are mutating.

Comment: @Yeo It’s still not correct because Python has no primitives: everything is an object. It just so happens that numbers in Python cannot be modified, only reassigned, which of course reassigns the reference.