# Python lists, increment & return modified list

Tags: python, list

The below code doesn't work as intended:

```
l = [1,1]

def modifyList(list):
  for element in list:
    element += 1
  return list
```

The list I expect when I run:

```
modifyList(l)
```

is [2,2] instead of [1,1]

Can someone explain why python acts this way?

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647261/why-i-cant-re-assign-a-variable-in-a-for-loop-in-python?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

You need to access the list element using the index and increment:

```
def modifyList(lst):
    for ind, _ in enumerate(lst):
        lst[ind] += 1 # access list element by index and increment
    return lst
```

Or use a list comprehension and simply add 1 to each element:

```
def modifyList(lst):
    lst[:] = [ele +1 for ele in lst] # lst[:] changes the original list
    return lst
```

If you are modifying the original list in place, you don't really need a return value, if you want to create a new list then just return the list comprehension: `return [ele +1 for ele in lst]`

```
def mod_in_place(lst):
   lst[:] = [ele +1 for ele in lst] # lst[:] changes the original list
```

Now just calling the function passing the list will change the original list/object passed in:

```
In [3]: l = [1,1]   
In [4]: mod_in_place(l)    
In [5]: l
Out[5]: [2, 2]
```

To create a new list/object:

```
def create_new_list(lst):
    return [ele + 1 for ele in lst]
```

Now create a new list leaving the original as is:

```
In [7]: l = [1,1]  
In [8]: l2 = create_new_list(l)    
In [9]: l
Out[9]: [1, 1]   # original list not changed
In [10]: l2
Out[10]: [2, 2]
```

Your code just creates a new object with `element += 1`, ints are immutable so you are not affecting the object stored in the list. If you had a mutable object in your list and you mutated that then the changes would be reflected but in your code you just create a new variable temporarily and throw it away.

Comment: Thank you - one question, why do we need to say `lst[:] = comp` rather than just `lst = comp` -- why the use of the slice?

Comment: @PipS, it changes the original list the same way the for loop does, you can remove the return, print the original list `l` and you will see the changes. If you want a new list as I commented in my answer just return the list comp

Comment: Can you modify a list in place using a function? I thought the parameters were implicitly separate copies, and you'd need to specify them as global or use return to actually modify the parameter passed in.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, no you are just passing a reference.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that, when you say:

```
for element in list:
    element += 1
```

You are taking one element from the list and assigning it to variable `element` but this will not update the element in the list. Hence the list remains as it is, unmodified.

To modify the list:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i]+=1
```

This will increment each element by `1` iteratively.