# List of dicts is updated - List of numbers is not updated

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

When I do this:

```
i = [5, 6, 7, 5]

for el in i:

    el = 2

print(i)
# [5, 6, 7, 5]
```

the list is not updated (which is a trivial observation for someone who knows Python).

But when I do this:

```
i = [{'id': 5}, {'id': 6}, {'id': 7}, {'id': 5}]

for el in i:

    el['id'] = 2

print(i)
# [{'id': 2}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 2}]
```

then the list is updated.

Why is this exactly happening?

Even if a list of dicts is updated in this way, is this considered a bad technique to do something like that?

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647261/why-i-cant-re-assign-a-variable-in-a-for-loop-in-python

Answer (score 1):

This is because python dict is mutable and not integer. this is why the list change. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutable-vs-immutable-objects-in-python/)

If you want to change you list you have to access the element by his index i.e `l[i] = 2`

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

When you are running this code:

```
i = [5, 6, 7, 5]

for el in i:

    el = 2
```

you are just reassigning a variable inside of the loop without making any changes in the original list.
To change the list you need to provide i[el] = 2 inside the loop.

But when you are running:

```
i = [{'id': 5}, {'id': 6}, {'id': 7}, {'id': 5}]

for el in i:

    el['id'] = 2
```

You are actually accessing the value in each dictionary in the list by the key and changing each value in the loop.

I suppose it's logically correct, so it's not a bad practice at all.

*Please, correct me if i am wrong in comments - I am not a coder.*