# Is there duplication of data among Qt model items?

Tags: python, qt, memory, pyqt, pyside

There is a standard way of representing data for use in `QAbstractItemModels`, in which there is a separate data item class that stores data about an item, and its position in the model.

The [simpletreemodel](https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/blob/master/src/PyQt-gpl-5.3.2/examples/itemviews/simpletreemodel/simpletreemodel.py) example (in Python) illustrates a pretty standard way of doing this, where the data is stored in a `TreeItem` that is initialized with:

```
class TreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        self.parentItem = parent
        self.itemData = data
        self.childItems = []
```

Note that each `TreeItem` instance contains its relevant item-specific data (self.itemData), but also has a list of its child items (which are `TreeItems` themselves), as well as its parent item (also a `TreeItem`) as attributes.

Why is this not a really inefficient use of memory? Let's focus on item B in the following tree diagram:

```
A
|
|--B
|  |--C
|  |
|  |--D
|
|-E
```

Naively, it seems B's data will be stored *four* times once the full data tree is constructed. It will be returned by `A.childItems[0]`, `C.parentItem`, `D.parentItem`, and of course `B.itemData`.

Is there some Python magic under the hood that makes this *not* be an inefficient use of memory?

Note: even though these types of data containers are used a lot when `QAbstract*Model` is subclassed, these containers themselves actually contain no Qt (no Qt classes are being subclassed in the code for `TreeItem`). So this is really an elementary *Python* question, not a *Qt* question.

**Possibly Relevant Post**

[How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python)

Comment: I don't know about Python, but in C++ `parentItem` and `childItems` will be pointers to relevant items. They do not contain any user data, so there's no any 'data duplication'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, variable names are references to objects so all these different expressions actually refer to the same object ie the same data in memory. There is no duplication of objects, although there is duplication of references. So in your example, `A.childItems[0]`, `C.parentItem`, and `D.parentItem` are all *references* to the same object, `B`. Hence `A.childItems[0].itemData`, `C.parentItem.itemData`, `D.parentItem.itemData` all refer to the same `B.itemData` object.

Side Note related to the LEGB article mentioned in neuronet's comment: If any of A, B, C or D modify the object that `itemData` references (by calling a method or setting a property or data member on that object), then all of the others will see the change. However, if any of `A.childItems[0]`, `C.parentItem`, or `D.parentItem` get re-assigned to a different object, it only affects the parent: `A.childItems[0] = something` only affects the first element in `A.childItems`; `C.parentItem` and `D.parentItem`, and any other references to `B`, still refer to `B`.

You might find the answers on [Python variable reference assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222440/python-variable-reference-assignment) useful but I don't find them all that clear. I prefer [Is Python pass-by-reference or pass-by-value](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/), see what you think.

Comment: what you are saying makes intuitive sense, but then I remember reading things like "Anybody using the terms variable, reference or call-by-value is most likely explaining Python the wrong way " (http://learnpython.pbworks.com/w/page/15956522/Assignment) and then I start to get confused again. Is there a standard resource to consult to walk through the ins and outs of this? E.g., is the following good? http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/scope_resolution_legb_rule.ipynb

Comment: @neuronet given that the Python documentation talks about reference counts for objects, I think its fair to ignore the semantics the pbworks article is trying to enforce.

Comment: @neuronet I read the two articles in your comment and the first one is  too confusing, not worth reading; the second is a very good article but the referencing aspect is, although related, implicit rather than explicit. I have extended my answer and provided what I think are better "references" to articles ;)

Comment: @Scholli very helpful stuff! That first article is funny and really good. Gets to the essence. I now appreciate that my question really is a basic Python question, as there is actually no Qt in there (the data class does not inherit from any of Qt's classes).

Comment: @three_pineapples that is a really good point....I should start using 'reference' again in Python :)

Answer (score 1):

As @schollii and @hank pointed out, PyQt and PySide are Python wrappers of C++ based Qt. So if Qt used objects/pointers for something (like the parent and children in the tree as you described), then Python's corresponding  variables also store references or pointer objects. Therefore there is no duplication of those objects in memory, just duplicate references or pointers to the same thing in memory.

These links are great reads on this subject:

https://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/c2341

http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn18

Comment: those are  really great reference I didn't appreciate before thanks. As I mentioned previously, I now better appreciate that my question really comes down to basic Python, as the data container classes (like TreeItem) actually contain no Qt at all! Even though such containers are fairly ubiquitous use when QAbstract*Model is subclassed.

Comment: But even if the underlying C++ data were not pointers but whole objects, the Python layer would still be using reference semantics for variable names, so you can't use the underlying C++ implementation as evidence of one or the other.

Comment: @schollii that is great piece of info. Thank you.