# Python .replace() reassigning multiple variables

Tags: python, str-replace

this is as much a conceptual question as a concrete one, and I haven't seen anyone ask this yet.  When reassigning an element of a list using Python's built-in .replace() function, I'm finding that not only the desired list is reassigned, but the original list that it was derived from is reassigned as well.  This is probably best explained using an example:

```
> x = ['apple','banana','potato']
> y = x
> print x;print y
 ['apple','banana','potato']
 ['apple','banana','potato']
```

Now, if I try to reassign an element of `y` using .replace(), it also reassigns to `x`:

```
> y[0] = y[0].replace('e','3')
> print x; print y
 ['appl3','banana','potato']
 ['appl3','banana','potato']
```

Now I have lost my original `x` variable, which I wanted to keep.  Can anyone explain why this is happening and/or how to avoid this?

Comment: Indeed, this is exactly what I was looking for, but could not find.  Much appreciated!

Comment: read that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222440/python-variable-reference-assignment

Comment: a = {"a":"apple", "b":"car"};b=a.copy();b["a"] = b["a"].replace("e",str(3));print b,a