# How can I update a "self" variable in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having trouble understanding how to instantiate a class, and update that instances variables. If I `__init__` a series of `self.x` variables, then instance that class, I want to update self.x = 40. However, `self.x` always stays constant.

I have a feeling I'm not wrapping my head around the class variable, init variable, and instanced class variables. I can always access them, I just can't seem to change them. I have coded an example of what I am trying to do.

```
class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board

    def play_game(self):
        print(self.board.sheet[0])
        number_one = int(input("Please enter a number."))
        self.board.a = number_one
        number_two = int(input("Please enter another number."))
        self.board.b = number_two
        number_three = int(input("Please enter a third number."))
        self.board.c = number_three
        number_four = int(input("Please enter a final number."))
        self.board.d = number_four

        print("Thank you! List updated.")

        print(self.board.sheet[0])


class ScoreBoard(object):
     def __init__(self):
        self.a = "_____"
        self.b = "_____"
        self.c = "_____"
        self.d = "_____"

        self.sheet = [f"""

            1. Number One:    {self.a}
            2. Number Two:    {self.b}
            3. Number Three:  {self.c}
            4. Number Four:   {self.d}
            """]

new_board = ScoreBoard()
new_game = Engine(new_board)
new_game.play_game()
```

When I print `self.board.sheet[0]` I would like to show the numbers instead of the lines for `self.a` through `self.d`.

Comment: What does *show the numbers instead of the lines* mean?

Comment: It should read:
1. Number One:    40   (from ```self.board.a = number_one```)
not
1. Number One: _____ (this is the init value)

Answer (score 1):

You need to recompute `self.sheet` after `self.a` through `self.d` are set. After `self.sheet` is assigned it just contains a simple string. That string isn't automatically updated when the fields are changed; you have to do it yourself.

Better yet, make `sheet` a method rather than a static variable.

```
class ScoreBoard(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "_____"
        self.b = "_____"
        self.c = "_____"
        self.d = "_____"

    def sheet(self):
        return f"""
            1. Number One:    {self.a}
            2. Number Two:    {self.b}
            3. Number Three:  {self.c}
            4. Number Four:   {self.d}
            """
```

Comment: I like the return better. In trying this on a larger scale it does not work since it is not explicit which ```self.x``` to assign ```number_one```. I have to set a variable ```a_number = self.board.dict.get(number)  # gets self.a - self.z``` and then set ```a_number = number_one```. At this point ```self.a``` is still ```"_____"``` and not the new number.

Comment: This is because with `a_number = number_one`, you are reassigning the *reference* of `a_number` and not changing the *value* previously referenced by it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222440/python-variable-reference-assignment

Comment: If you're still unclear why this is working, I would start a new question for that.