# How to In-place reassign a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose there are a few variables that all share the same value, and the variable `df_train` points to that value.

Now if I reassign `df_train` to some other frame, all the other variables that pointed at the same object as df_train are now pointing at the old value:

```
mydata = [df_train, df_test]
df_train = pd.concat( ... ) 
# now the mydata is no longer sharing the same value as df_train
```

Is it possible to reassign a dataframe in-place? something like:

```
mydata = [df_train, df_test]
df_train.set(pd.concat(...))
# now mydata still shares state with df_train
```

Comment: I think this is something similar to what you are trying to do:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11222835/11610186

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, albeit a somewhat smelly one, by using the `__init__` method:

```py
mydata = [df_train, df_test]
df_other = # ...
df_train.__init__(df_other) 
# now mydata still shares state with df_train
```