# Python Ordered linked list confusion with referencing the right name

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

So I'm following this linked list, and it is an ordered linked list. For reference here is the code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self,newnext):
        self.next = newnext

class OrderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self,item):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        stop = False
        while current != None and not stop:
            if current.getData() > item:
                stop = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.getNext()

        temp = Node(item)
        if previous == None:
            temp.setNext(self.head)
            self.head = temp
        else:
            temp.setNext(current)
            previous.setNext(temp)

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current != None:
            count = count + 1
            current = current.getNext()

        return count


mylist = OrderedList()
mylist.add(31)
mylist.add(77)
mylist.add(17)
mylist.add(93)
mylist.add(26)
mylist.add(54)

print(mylist.size())
```

As you can see, when calling `mylist.size()`, it will return a size of 6 because there are 6 things that were added. But in the add method, specifically the lines:

```
if previous == None:
            temp.setNext(self.head)
            self.head = temp
```

If I were to change `self.head = temp` to `current = temp` it would return a size of 0. Which means that the rest of the numbers didn't get referenced. But why is this the case, I thought that since we defined `current = self.head` earlier, changing `self.head = temp` to `current = temp` would yield the same results?

Answer (score 1):

```
current = self.head
current = temp
```

The first line above will make `current` refer to whatever `self.head` refers to.
The second line makes `current` refer to `temp`, but it does not also make `self.head` refer to `temp`.

You can think of `current` as a reference to some underlying object (that also happens to be referenced by `self.head`). Reassigning `current` to `temp` does not change what `self.head` refers to.

This can be a common confusion when working with Python and there is a lot more info on the way objects and names are dealt with. See e.g. [Python variable reference assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222440/python-variable-reference-assignment)