# list1 is never assigned equal to list2 anywhere in my code, but still values of list1 are being copied to list2

Tags: python, list

I tried to debug the code with some print statements. So, I am presenting the whole code here.

```
l = ['one', 'two', 'three',  'four', 'five']

l1 = list()
count = 0
l2 = list()

for r in range(len(l)):

    print(r, 'this is r')
    print()
    if count < 2:
   
        l1.append(l[r])
        print(l1)
        print(l2)  #when the loop runs for the third time l2 is automatically updating to l1, which 
                   #is now ['one','two,'three'].Why?
        
        count += 1
        
    if count == 2:
    
        l2.append(l1)
        print(l2, 'this is l2')
        print()
        count = 0
    
print(l2)
```

I think the output of l2 should be : [['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']]

But the output I am getting is : [['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']]

Comment: Change l2.append(l1) to l2.append(l1.copy()) - passing in the reference is referring to the original object

Comment: But why is this happening, I am using the append function , I am not saying l2 = l1

Comment: I think the second and the third answer explains it quite well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222440/python-variable-reference-assignment